# Creation of PhantomJS webdriver causes user input problems in Python over ssh session

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver, ssh, phantomjs

User input to my Python program does not respond most of the time when I run it remotely and try to use a PhantomJS webdriver. Everything executes fine, same as it does when I run it locally, except the majority of keypresses don't register at a prompt from raw_input(). I have to hit a key (on average) three times for it to actually show up in the console.

This is *only* on raw_input in my program after it creates a PhantomJS instance. I singled out the issue by setting `w = None`, where `w` is the webdriver. After doing this, user input continued working as it should throughout the program.

I can start another ssh session and stdin works fine. I can also start another instance of my program (`python run.py`) and before that instance creates a webdriver, raw_input works fine in it as well. I have tried running `top` in another ssh session and there is no load at all on my server. So only input to the parent python process is affected.

I figure best case scenario, someone can help me get to the root of the problem. I don't have the tools to narrow down the cause of this. Thanks!

---

---

**Additional info that might be relevant**

`ps -aux` in an ssh session gives me these related processes:

```
[TTY: pts/1, STAT: S+] python run.py
[TTY: pts/1, STAT: S1+] node /usr/local/bin/phantomjs --webdriver=52129
[TTY: pts/1, STAT: S1+] /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs --webdriver=52129
```

All of them using negligible mem and cpu

Selenium webdriver creation is customized- (summarized) customdriver.py:

```
def mkDriver(params):
    # params aren't relevant because this is the setup I always use on the server
    w = webdriver.PhantomJS({'phantomjs.page.settings.loadImages': 'false'})
    loginToFacebook(w)
    loginToTwitter(w)
    # for later- w.quit() leaves phantom process running
    w.phantomjsPID = collectPhantomjsPID()
```

...Though I don't think the problem relates to any of the other statements there, this function finishes execution and my program continues.

Some notes:

- laptop: OS X El Capitan, 2.4GHz intel core i5, 8GB memory
- server: Ubuntu Server 14.04, 2.0GHz intel xeon e5, 8GB memory - I was using a micro .ec2 I set up myself, but someone set this up for me to give me something more powerful to play with. It's running on IBM Softlayer.
- Before I asked: read about stdin and stdout over ssh, about paramiko as a solution (wouldn't give the behavior I wanted), checked if there is a better python function to use than raw_input, differences with psuedo-tty on and off upon ssh (don't think this applies to how I am running my program), and tried using the -u flag with python.
- Initially all raw_input() statements gave an EOFError when I ran my program on the server. I "fixed" this using [this solution](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/python-raw_input-and-putty-on-remote-server-514891/) I found, which was to import readline in all modules using raw_input. No idea why it worked. I know raw_input() is derived from sys.stdin.readline...
- If you're looking at the pseudocode below, the purpose of this was to make changes to the ui and the functions it calls, then continue to test, without ever having to regenerate anything in `resources` (most importantly the webdriver, which takes a long time to load). The structure also makes it easy to have a few pre-written tests.

Overview of the modules...

run.py:

```
params = raw_input('enter parameters')

w = customdriver.mkDriver(params)
t = tweepy_connection()
f = facebook_Graph_API_conection()
s = sqlAlchemy_engine()
resources = [w, t, f, s]

while True:
    choice = raw_input('1: break, 2: restart ui')
    if choice == '1':
        break
    elif choice == '2':
        reload(ui.py)
        ui.ui_function(resources)
    else:
        continue
```

ui.py:

```
def ui_function(resources):
    while True:
        choice = raw_input('1: break, 2: functionA, 3: functionB')
        if choice == '1':
            break
        elif choice == '2':
            reload(file1)
            params = raw_input('enter parameters')
            file1.functionA(resources, params)
        elif choice == '3':
            reload(file2)
            params = raw_input('enter some other parameters')
            file2.functionB(resources, params)
     else:
         continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the raw inputs hang when you only create a PhantomJS instance or do you do any headless browsing with it? If you're browsing, it would make sense that raw_inputs hang as each website request will consequently stall the shell.

Have you considered multi-threading it?

Comment: Can you elaborate? The only browsing (before the problem) is the login to twitter and facebook, it stalls indefinitely after that, though the webdriver is just sitting idle. And no I've never considered multithreading, I've never needed to when running locally and it seemed overkill.

Comment: PJS won't release it's resources (which are also the raw_input resources) until it has finished it's request, not to mention it has a history of memory leakages. If you're not a fan of multi-threading, you might want to consider webdrivers wait commands to make your program a bit more manageable.

Comment: Also wanted to add, that webdrivers javascript handling (eg. `w.execute_script("document.querySelector('.button').click()")` ) gives you shell control back immediately. Might be in some cases better than `w.click()`

Comment: Yes I see how an execute_script might be helpful then... But I use wait commands pretty regularly, wait_until_element_clickable etc, to make sure things only happen when they're possible, I don't see how this would help me getting back shell control. Shouldn't the shell on my mac be no different than the linux shell over ssh in regards to the resources?